# Normalize coordinates of an image

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, normalization

I am trying to create an object detection program in Python. The output should be the filename of the picture being analyzed, plus the "normalized coordinates" of the the object center.

Each image should be normalized as follows:

Top left = (0,0), Bottom left = (0,1), Top right = (1,0), Bottom right = (1,1)

Any advice or suggestions on how I can normalize the coordinates of each image?

Answer (score 2):

This simple function would get the job done:

```
def normalize_coordinates(row_i, col_j, img):
    num_rows, num_cols = img.shape[:2]
    x = col_j/(num_cols - 1.)
    y = row_i/(num_rows - 1.)
    return x, y
```

**Demo**

```
from skimage import io
from numpy import random

random.seed(42)
img = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/94l13.jpg')
row_i = random.randint(0, img.shape[0]) 
col_j = random.randint(0, img.shape[1]) 
x, y = normalize_coordinates(row_i, col_j, img)

print(f'row = {row_i}, column = {col_j}  >>>  x = {x:.2f}, y = {y:.2f}')
```

Output:

```
row = 102, column = 435  >>>  x = 0.71, y = 0.25
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this better than to use `import PIL` to first get the pixels in the image and then divide?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with PIL, but I would bet that you can normalize the coordinates through a similar approach using PIL.

Comment: the other thing is that I want to normalize the entire image first it appears that the script you have provided would only normalize the object center (correct me if Im wrong)- but this would not provide the accurate output...does that make sense?

Comment: The function `normalize_coordinates` converts the coordinates `(row_i, col_j)` of a single pixel into the normalized coordinates `(x, y)`. The value of the coordinate `row_i` [`col_j`] ranges from 0 to the maximum number of rows [columns] minus 1, and grows downwards [to the right], while the value of the normalized coordinate `x` [`y`] ranges from 0 to 1 and grows to the right [downwards].