# Can I draw using normalized coordinates in pyglet?

Tags: python, pyglet

In the pyglet graphics documentation, it demonstrates how to draw points in 2d space using the screen coordinates

```
pyglet.graphics.draw(2, pyglet.gl.GL_POINTS,
    ('v2i', (10, 15, 30, 35))
)
```

I want to be able to draw using the normalized coordinates, which range from [-1, 1] on each axis, but using the draw call normally, I must give the vertices in terms of pixel coordinates.

The reason I want to do this is that I will be drawing functions of both domain and range [-1, 1], so it is very fitting to draw using the normalized coordinates and not have to worry about converting.

Comment: I don't think you can. However, what you could do is create a [normalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48524516/normalize-coordinates-of-an-image) function that you can pass the values into. The example above takes, `x,y` and `constraints`, but you could easily adapt that to take a tuple and work your way through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assuming my math is correct *(which it most certainly isn't)*, these functions should return what you're looking for:

```
def normalize(cords, constraint):
    x_ratio, y_ratio = 1/constraint.width, 1/constraint.height

    result = []
    for x,y in zip(*[iter(cords)] * 2):
        nx = ((x-(constraint.width/2))*x_ratio)*2
        ny = ((y-(constraint.height/2))*y_ratio)*2
        result += [nx, ny]

        print(x,y, '->', nx, ny)

    return result

def complicate(cords, constraint):
    x_ratio, y_ratio = 1/constraint.width, 1/constraint.height

    result = []
    for x,y in zip(*[iter(cords)] * 2):
        nx = ((x/x_ratio)/2)+(constraint.width/2)
        ny = ((y/y_ratio)/2)+(constraint.height/2)
        result += [nx, ny]

        print(x, y, '->', nx, ny)
    return result
```

And you could use them as such:

```
pyglet.graphics.draw(2, pyglet.gl.GL_POINTS,
    ('v2i', normalize((10, 15, 30, 35), window))
)
```

or

```
pyglet.graphics.draw(2, pyglet.gl.GL_POINTS,
    ('v2i', complicate((-0.975, -0.95, -0.925, -0.883), window))
)
```

You probably want a generic way of storing the two worlds in one place. And work with them as one singular object that makes sense no matter what you put in. So you can treat both normalized coordinates and coordinates as the same thing.

You could do this by doing something like this:

```
class cordinates():
    def __init__(self, cords, constraint=None):
        if not constraint: constraint = window
        self.constraint = constraint

        if min(cords) > -1 and max(cords) < 1:
            self.type = 'normalized'
        else:
            self.type = 'complicated'

        self.cords = cords

    def normalize(self, constraint=None):
        if not constraint: constraint = self.constraint
        x_ratio, y_ratio = 1/constraint.width, 1/constraint.height

        result = []
        for x,y in zip(*[iter(self.cords)] * 2):
            nx = ((x-(constraint.width/2))*x_ratio)*2
            ny = ((y-(constraint.height/2))*y_ratio)*2
            result += [nx, ny]

            print(x,y, '->', nx, ny)

        return result

    def complicate(self, constraint=None):
        if not constraint: constraint = self.constraint
        x_ratio, y_ratio = 1/constraint.width, 1/constraint.height

        result = []
        for x,y in zip(*[iter(self.cords)] * 2):
            nx = ((x/x_ratio)/2)+(constraint.width/2)
            ny = ((y/y_ratio)/2)+(constraint.height/2)
            result += [nx, ny]

            print(x,y, '->', nx, ny)

        return result

    def __iter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.cords

    def __repr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return str(self.cords)

pyglet.graphics.draw(2, pyglet.gl.GL_POINTS,
    ('v2i', coordinates((-0.975, -0.95, -0.925, -0.883)).complicate() )
)

pyglet.graphics.draw(2, pyglet.gl.GL_POINTS,
    ('v2i', coordinates((10, 15, 30, 35)) )
)
```

You could even build away `.complicate()` by doing guess-work based off `self.type` and always return coordinates.

```
def __iter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.type == 'normalized':
        return self.complicate()
    else:
        return self.cords
```

I normally just work with one type of object, so I might not be the best teacher in this matter. But this makes sense to me, and hopefully it's useful for you. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and pythonic answer.  I have implemented something similar in my code, I call from_window and to_window functions to convert the coordinates between the normalized and screenspace coordinates